# Adding icon button in tab material design lite

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

Is it possible to add icon button in tab in Material Design Lite? The tab is only a  tag so I don't know to include a icon button within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you have to fix the css. Perhaps only place the icon there instead of the complete button.

```html
<a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab ">
  <span class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </span>
</a>
```

http://codepen.io/Schnueggel/pen/OyYjVO